# Make a new list with a certain order, but skip some indices on if condition

Tags: python, list, indices

I am trying to make an new list in a certain order that relies on another list. It should make an list with an order i specifed, but if an item in that other list is x it should skip that index and continue with the order without skipping an item in the order.

start:

```
days_list = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']
x = 'rest'
order = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

after i changed the days_list:

```
changed_days_list = ['sunday', 'monday', x, 'wednesday', x, 'friday', x]
```

The output should look like this:

```
example_output = ['a', 'b', 'rest', 'c', 'rest', 'a', 'rest']
```

I have tried with for and while loops, but i can't figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you typed wrong output in the question?

Comment: example_output = ['a', 'b', 'rest', 'c', 'rest', 'a', 'b', 'rest'] or example_output = ['a', 'b', 'rest', 'c', 'rest', 'a',  'rest']

Comment: your desire output/

Comment: I don't understand your outputs.Why first output has `x` in some places?

Comment: maybe you should work with `zip(days_list, changed_days_list)` to see where you need `rest`, and with `itertools.cycle(order)` to put other values on list.

Comment: You can just play with the index and lenth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `for`-loop to check every value on `changed_days_list` and put new value from `order` when it is not `rest`. And you could use [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to get value from `order`.

```
import itertools

x = 'rest'

order = ['a', 'b', 'c']
changed_days_list = ['sunday', 'monday', x, 'wednesday', x, 'friday', x]

cycle = itertools.cycle(order)

result = []

for item in changed_days_list:
    if item == x:
        result.append(item)
    else:
        next_value = next(cycle)
        result.append(next_value)
        
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'rest', 'c', 'rest', 'a', 'rest']
```